# how to solve error = "page not found 404 during Spring Application"

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-boot

I am trying to make a postRequest and trying to get the object from request  but the code is not getting executed. It is not getting inside the method.

I have already tried adding `@componentScan` in config files and `@EntityScan`

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/verify")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
public class Verify {

    @PostMapping(path = "/members", consumes = "application/json")
    public String verify(@RequestBody DeviceDetails device) {
        try {
            System.out.println(device.getIpAddress());
            //return "1";
            return "hi";
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            return "hi from err";
        }
   }
```

I expect that it should print hi to console and it should print IP Address

[image: Here is the postman response]

Comment: How are you executing it?

Comment: I added one image I am sending request using postman

Answer (score 1):

You're using wrong method - get (in the screenshot from postman), whereas in your mapping you're defining a post endpoint: `@PostMapping(path = "/members", consumes = "application/json")`. You need to change it to `GetMapping` or simply use post in postman. Also - check the urls and bodies if they match.

Answer (score 0):

The above code has a path of `/api/verify/members` but in postman, it is `/api/verify/call`. In Postman, please correct it to `/api/verify/members`, change **GET** method to the **POST** method, and also please check if the **JSON** **body** is proper. Once these are fixed it should work.